# Print duplicate entries in a file using linux commands

Tags: file, shell, sorting, unix, uniq

I have a file called foo.txt, which consists of:

```
abc
zaa
asd
dess
zaa
abc
aaa
zaa
```

I want the output to be stored in another file as:

```
this text abc appears 2 times
this text zaa appears 3 times
```

I have tried the following command, but this just writes duplicate entries and their number.

```
sort foo.txt | uniq --count --repeated > sample.txt
```

Example of output of above command:

```
abc 2
zaa 3
```

How do I add the line "this text appears x times" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk is your friend:

```
sort foo.txt | uniq --count --repeated | awk '{print($2" appears "$1" times")}'
```

Comment: Thanku !!Worked well